# SSH into tutum node

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, tutum

I've been trying to SSH into tutum node,

[this](https://support.tutum.co/support/solutions/articles/5000553071-sshing-into-a-tutum-node) approach seems to be pretty straightforward but I keep getting *Permission denied (publickey)* message.

The node is running (pretty much blank) Ubuntu 14.04.

After few unsucessfull tries, I connected through terminal on Tutum website, installed SSH related packages, inserted my key into *.ssh/authorized_keys* manually. Still without any luck when trying to connect from my local machine.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to connect using approach mentioned in the guide above in combination with tutum-cli. The command is then

> tutum container exec **container**.**stack** **command**

Command can be for example **/bin/bash**

Answer (score 1):

Since you have command line access to the tumtum machine, use this command  on the server, to see what your actual errors are when attempting to login to the machine.

`tail -f /var/log/auth.log`

By default, Ubuntu writes all login attempts to that auth.log file and tail -f opens the file and keeps it open. When you attempt to login from your local machine, you should see an informative message on the server, that will let you know exactly what is wrong or at least give a much more informative result, when you search the message in Google.

Depending on the error message, you may find that your authorized_keys file on the tumtum node may have the wrong permissions, or just be an incomplete key.

What command are you using to ssh into the new server? If you followed their guide exactly, make sure you're using the -i flag in the ssh command to specify your private key and not the public one. To help clarify, here's a more informative version of their ssh string.

`ssh -i /path/to/private_key_file username@server.ip.adress`